# How to extend the access_token of a page in facebook using facebook python sdk

Tags: python, facebook

I am new in using facebook python sdk. I have to post in a fan page as the page admin. I can do this by using the page `access_token` and permissions. but problem is that the `access_token` expires after the user logout. I want an extended `access_token` for the page. Is there a way of doing it ?
I have googled but could not found useful information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the user log in again in order to renew the access token.

From the Facebook documentation:

> If the access token becomes invalid, the solution is to have the
>   person log in again, at which point you will be able to make API calls
>   on their behalf once more. The login flow your app uses for new people
>   should determine which method you need to adopt.

[Facebook Access Tokens Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)